# How to retrive assigned smarty template in prestashop?

Tags: templates, variables, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Ok, so I have some smarty variables assigned on the checkout page in my shop. Problem is that when I want to use them -for example

```
{$address_collection.firstname}
```

I get an undefined index notice. I am certainly doing something wrong, but what?

[image: Debug]

Answer (score 0):

on your screenshot `$address_collection` is array of objects, so to access  to array element you need to use key, like `$address_collection[124]` and this element will contains address object,
where to get first name:

`{$address_collection[124]->firstname}`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10705131)

Comment: @Viraj Nalawade explain your review, because I think this is correct answer

Comment: @sergilp you have edited the answer later.. Because you yourself released the worth of your original answer.. So don't ask for explanation.I m glad this answer is lot better. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If in smarty you want to access the array then you have to mention key of the array then you can use the values.If in your tpl file you want to print the array which you assigned then you have to write like

```
{var_dump($address_collection)}
```

Where $address_collection is the variable which from which you assigned values.
Now for access the values in your tpl file you have to mention key like:

```
{$address_collection['key_name']}
```

I hope it would help you.